# discord.js client.on("error") not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord.js

I have this simple bit of code:

```js
client.on("error", () => console.log('test'))
```

It seems like this is never called.
I tried making my bot do something it doesn't have permission to do but the bot just crashes and `test` is never logged. I'm wondering why it isn't and whether there is a way to handle errors besides putting everything in try/catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why that line is not called when you get the permission error. I suspect that the error handler doesn't pick up unhandled rejections. Essentially, think of any API Error like the permission error that occurs on a `Promise`. You could add a `.catch()` or `try/catch` on the error to catch it and do something with the error instead of interrupting or crashing your code execution.

I'm assuming that either: a) Discord's `error` event only triggers when an error is caught and not unhandled, or b) Discord API errors don't trigger that event. I don't know which, if any, of those theories is accurate. Maybe try causing different kinds of errors; the error you tested out was an API error, but you could also cause [discord.js library errors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#discord-js-errors) or even [standard JS errors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#js-errors) to see what happens.

As for how you could handle errors that are unhandled by a `try/catch` or `.catch()` in your code, you can use the `unhandledRejection` event listener on Node's `process` variable to handle most if not all of them.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.log('Test error:', error);
});
```

You can see an example [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#how-to-diagnose-api-errors) on the discord.js guide website.